# How to create a REST JSON API using Laravel 5.5 or Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, json, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

Am just starting out with laravel and i wanted to create a simple rest api that accepts json data and returns a json data but didnt seem to know how to do this. I was wondering if anyone could help.
below is what i want my controller to look like or do:

```
class MembersController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //return all members as json
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //leave this as empty
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // get user values as json
        // save value to database
       // return user data as json.
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //return single user dat as json
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //leave as empty
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //update value and return as json
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //delete value and also return deleted value as json
    }
}
```

How can i achieve the above using laravel. Mostly 5.5 or 5.4.
I dont seem to find anything that could be of help anywhere.

Comment: you can store data in array and then make use of json_encode ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not too hard; you can get the solution of such problem easily over the internet.

Anyway, you can accomplish this by using array and json_decode like below

```
 $data = ['staus' => 'ok',
          'id' => 10,
          'name'=>'something',
          'address'=>'something'
          ];
// encode this array to json strig you can use return or echo, print to generate the result
 return json_encode($data);
```

If you want to convert the model objects to json then you can simply use toJson function like below which comes with laravel framework

```
   return ModelName::all()->toJson();
   // for a single record retrieval
   return ModelName::find(1)->toJson();
```

Comment: Doesn't work when I do a post request using postman, it returns html containing several error messages mostly saying : TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68

Comment: token mismatch is problem of laravel, if you post form you need to send input with the name _token which is generated by laravel itself for security reason to prevent - Cross-Site Request Forgery(CSRF)

Comment: so how do I handle this, because I'm going to be calling my php rest from another server

Comment: you can make use of GET method to submit and token system to verify the request from authenticated users only

Comment: or you may disable the csrf look into https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-disable-csrf-middleware-on-certain-routes

Comment: if you find this answer is correct please accept answer as correct... thanks.. if you need help feel free